# Kronecker delta in the harmonic lattice potential energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, harmonic-oscillator

This is a rather mathematical question regarding a derivation of the harmonic lattice energy $\Phi^{ham}$ in a book about the quantum theory of solids. Specifically, I found the **third equivalence in Eqn. (1)** below is quite bizarre:

$$\begin{aligned}
\Phi^{\mathrm{harm}} &=\Phi_{0}+\frac{1}{4} \sum_{i \kappa, j \nu} \sum_{\alpha \beta}\left(u_{i \kappa, \alpha}-u_{j \nu, \alpha}\right) \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right)\left(u_{i \kappa, \beta}-u_{j \nu, \beta}\right) \\
&=\Phi_{0}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i j} \sum_{\kappa \alpha, \nu \beta} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right)\left(u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{i \kappa, \beta}-u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{j \nu, \beta}\right) \\
&=\Phi_{0}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i j} \sum_{\kappa \alpha, \nu \beta}\left\{\left[\sum_{j^{\prime} \nu^{\prime}} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j^{\prime}}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu^{\prime}}\right)\right] \delta_{i j} \delta_{\kappa \nu}\right.\\
&\left.-\phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(R_{i}+d_{\kappa}-R_{j}-d_{\nu}\right)\right\} u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{j \nu, \beta}\\
&=\Phi_{0}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i j} \sum_{\kappa \alpha, \nu \beta} u_{i \kappa, \alpha} D_{\kappa \nu, \alpha \beta}\left(R_{i}-R_{j}\right) u_{j \nu, \beta}
\end{aligned}\tag{1}$$

where

$$\Phi_{0}=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \kappa \neq j \nu} \phi\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right)$$
is the cohesive energy with $\boldsymbol{R}_i$ and $\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}$ being lattice coordinates and base atomic coordinates. $\phi$ is the interaction potential between two atoms. $u_{i\kappa,\alpha}$ represent the atomic displacement at $\alpha$ direction, and
$$\phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right)=\frac{\partial^{2} \phi\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right)}{\partial R_{i \alpha} \partial R_{i \beta}}.$$

What confuses me in (1) is the part in the square brackets. The intention of the author is to use the product $u_{i\kappa,\alpha}u_{j\nu,\beta}$ throughout the derivation. The author later uses the terms in the curly bracket to define a matrix,
$$\begin{aligned}
D_{\kappa \nu, \alpha \beta}\left(R_{i}-R_{j}\right)=&\left[\sum_{j^{\prime} \nu^{\prime}} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(R_{i}+d_{\kappa}-R_{j^{\prime}}-d_{\nu^{\prime}}\right)\right] \delta_{i j} \delta_{\kappa \nu} \\
&-\phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(R_{i}+d_{\kappa}-R_{j}-d_{\nu}\right)
\end{aligned}\tag{2}$$

But why is
$$\left[\sum_{j^{\prime} \nu^{\prime}} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j^{\prime}}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu^{\prime}}\right)\right] \delta_{i j} \delta_{\kappa \nu}u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{j \nu, \beta}=\phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right)\left.u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{i \kappa, \beta}\right.\tag{3}$$

I was trying to use the properties of Kronecker delta to understand (3) but couldn't find any useful explanation so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It essentially follows from a bunch of relabelings of the dummy indices. In the second line of eqn (1), you have the sum
$$ 
\sum_{i j} \sum_{\kappa \alpha, \nu \beta} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right) u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{i \kappa, \beta}.  $$
First relabel the indices $j\to j'$ and $\nu\to\nu'$ to rewrite this as
$$ \sum_{i j'} \sum_{\kappa \alpha, \nu' \beta} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j'}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu'}\right) u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{i \kappa, \beta} $$
Since the labels $j$ and $\nu$ are now `free', we can write
$$ 
  u_{i \kappa, \beta} = \sum_{j,\nu} \delta_{ij} \delta_{\kappa\nu} u_{j \nu, \beta},  
$$
so that the sum above becomes
$$ \sum_{i j} \sum_{\kappa \alpha, \nu \beta}\sum_{j^{\prime} \nu^{\prime}} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j^{\prime}}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu^{\prime}}\right) \delta_{i j} \delta_{\kappa \nu} u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{j \nu, \beta}, $$
which is what you have in the third line of eqn (1).

PS: As for eqn (3), one needs to remember that the equality of two sums does not imply equality of individual terms i.e., $\sum_i a_i = \sum_i b_i$ does not imply that $a_i = b_i \forall i$. Thus, eqn (3) does not follow from from eqn (1), since you cannot simply forget about $\sum_{i\kappa, j\nu}$.

Comment: Thx! This is very helpful!

Comment: @Sizhe You're welcome!